# Autofill field below if first field is selected using Select2 YII2

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, yii2

I'm developing HRMS on Yii2
I have this Displacing Employee Form,3 fields using 3 tables,which is 
displacing,employee,and department
i'm using Kartik/Select2 widget on Employee field,
databases i developed is more like this
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bODoL.png)

if i want to make an output like this
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj5NA.png)

What should i do ?
i tried some code like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'EmployeeId')->widget(Select2::classname(), 
[
'data'=>$listData,
'options' => ['id' => 'EmployeeId'],
'pluginOptions' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Employee Name',
                    'changeOnReset'=>'$.post
                ("index.php?r=project/lists&id='.'"+$(this).val(),function(data) 
                    { $("select#currentDept").html(data);
                    }
                );'
                   ],
                   ])?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'currentDept')->dropDownList($dataList,['prompt'=>'Choose Department','readonly' => !$model->isNewRecord]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'DeptID')->dropDownList($dataList,['prompt'=>'Choose Department']) ?>
```

it worked,but the CurrentDept Field is not generating

Comment: put id=>currentDept in dropdown like this 

<?= $form->field($model, 'currentDept')->dropDownList($dataList,'options' => ['id' => 'currentDept'],['prompt'=>'Choose Department','readonly' => !$model->isNewRecord]) ?>

Comment: i get an unexpected double arrow,i'll try again,

Comment: I think its better to use depdrop widget. dependent dropdown karik widget 
http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop

Comment: i already did,but it still shows the other data on currentDept,and i put an read only,it still can be modified,clickable.i'm trying to get the currentDept values from modifying action ID like displaced/view?id=1,i get the value from id=1

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link:
http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2.
You can use "pluginEvents" for the same.

```
pluginEvents = [
    "change" => "function() { log('change'); }",
    "select2:opening" => "function() { log('select2:opening'); }",
    "select2:open" => "function() { log('open'); }",
    "select2:closing" => "function() { log('close'); }",
    "select2:close" => "function() { log('close'); }",
    "select2:selecting" => "function() { log('selecting'); }",
    "select2:select" => "function() { log('select'); }",
    "select2:unselecting" => "function() { log('unselecting'); }",
    "select2:unselect" => "function() { log('unselect'); }"
];
```

You may use the select event and fill the other field using the callback function.
Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: i haven't understand about json,but i'm still working on pluginEvent

Comment: Did you try http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/723/creating-a-dependent-dropdown-from-scratch-in-yii2/

Comment: i did,yesterday.but haven't worked,i worked on json from the link you gave.it's interesting